# Hazelcast Management Center - Performance Issues

Tags: hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast 3.6 enterprise version and All maps are configured as HD (native memory). We have 3 cluster node with 6GB heap and 18 GB native memory

Config :

```html
<map name="map">
        <in-memory-format>NATIVE</in-memory-format>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
                <map-store enabled="true" initial-mode="LAZY">
                  <class-name><class name></class-name>
                  <write-delay-seconds>1</write-delay-seconds>
                  <write-batch-size>1000</write-batch-size>
                  <write-coalescing>true</write-coalescing>
                </map-store>
    </map>

 <management-center enabled="true">ip:port/mancenter</management-center>
```

Issue is when we load testing the Hazelcast with and without management center enabled , there is huge performance difference.

With Out management center  enabled :  there is no difference in response time as the time pass

With management center  : There is a huge time delay in response time . (after same response time as  With Out management center  enabled) , there is sudden increase in response time.

Question : Is there a overhead in using management center ? Why this is happen time to time ?

Comment: When NATIVE storage format is used, stats collection was an expensive operation in previous versions than 3.7. Do you see same slowness with 3.7?

Comment: Actually I haven't checked with the 3.7, we were using 3.6 version. What we could see was there was a thread running in each hazelcast server for communications with the management center. As you suggested we'll try with 3.7 version. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

With 3.7 CPU usage in the hazelcast server was minimum , compared to 3.6 with management center enabled in all cluster servers.

3.6 : 
[Hazelcast 3.6 - CPU utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufMqO.png)

3.7 : 
[Hazelcast 3.7 - CPU utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU7K8.png)